# I'm looking for a word that begins with C,and means that a topic has been previously researched/studied

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't actually know if one exists but it would make my life easier if anyone could think of one.

Comment: Is this for a crossword puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

It might be a stretch, but perhaps you could say that the subject has already been *covered*?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/covered

> 1. To deal with; treat of: *The book covers the feminist movement.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, english.stackexchange.com uses *Closed* when a question has been previously researched/studied.

Comment: Cutely observed!

Answer (score -2):

Besides *covered*, consider also the following words, which when used figuratively of a field, imply it has been studied or perhaps exhausted: *cultivated, crosschecked, consummated, construed, [conquered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conquered), clarified, [circumscribed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circumscribed), chronicled, checked, [characterized](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/characterized), catechized*, and less suitably, *capitulated*.  For a humorous touch, consider *[coauthored](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coauthored)*; eg, “That area has already been coauthored to death”.